# Does a BasicMed certificate need to be printed to be valid?

Tags: faa, basicmed

I understand the logic behind the FAA wanting a physical card on the pilot's person-- it's so an FAA rep can revoke the license on the spot. However, this logic doesn't apply in the slightest to the medical.

Do the Certificate and the Checklist, both required for BasicMed validity, have to be printed out or is it legal to fly with them in digital form, e.g. on a phone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

#### TLDR;

**Hard-copies are not required**, as per FAA Notice `8900.420`.

---

##### Justification

[FAA Notice 8900.420 - Demonstrating Eligibility to Operate Under BasicMed](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Notice/N_8900.420.pdf) states the following in paragraph **6. a. (2) Documents Required to be Retained by the Airman**:

> (2) **Documents Required to be Retained by the Airman**. In accordance with
> § 61.113(i)(3)(ii) and part 68, § 68.3(b)(1), an airman must retain in his or her logbook a
> certificate of completion from an authorized BasicMed medical education course. The airman is
> required under § 61.113(i)(3)(i) to retain, in his or her logbook, the CMEC required under § 68.7.
> **These documents may be stored in a physical paper logbook, or electronically in any format, as
> long as the airman can produce an accurate and legible representation of these documents at the
> request of the FAA.** Neither of these documents needs to be in the pilot’s personal possession in
> any form when operating under BasicMed.

*(emphasis is mine)*

Comment: perfect! I took the liberty of reformatting your answer to make the conclusion easiest for search engines to find. If this formatting is something you don't like, don't hesitate to revert it.